# Web monitoring tool: keeps on sending notification while it shouldn't

Tags: php, laravel

I developed a web monitoring tool. it is supposed to check the status code of the website and decide either it is up or down.It is going a good job if the response code is 200, it is saved as up in the database, otherwise down. More over it is supposed to send notification if the status code changes, that is either from up to down or vice versa, (it checks the new resCode(response code) with the last status code saved in the database)). but if the website is always up, don't send a notification. but if the website is down, check the alert frequency and send a notification. the function sendNotification is responsible for this, but for some reason and getting spam of notifications. it just keeps on sending a notification without checking the alert frequency and status changes. anyone who can review my code. tnx in advance.

```
 <?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use \GuzzleHttp\Client;
use App\Utilities\Reporter;
use GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException;
use App\Notification;
use App\Status;
use App\Setting;
use Carbon;
class GuzzleController extends Controller
{
    private $default_check_frequency;

    protected $client;

    protected $reporter;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->client = new Client();

        $this->reporter = new Reporter;

        $this->default_check_frequency = Setting::defaultCheckFrequency();


    }

    private function addStatusToNotification(Notification $notification, Status $status, $resCode)
    {
        $notification->statuses()->attach($status, [
            'values' => $resCode === 200
            ? 'up'
            : 'down'
            ]);
    }

    private function report(Notification $notification, $resCode)
    {
       if(empty($resCode)){
            $resCode = "no response found";
        }
        if($resCode <> 200){
                $this->reporter->slack($notification->website_url . ':' . '  is down' . ' this is the status code!' . ' @- ' .$resCode,
                        $notification->slack_channel);

                $this->reporter->mail($notification->email,$notification->website_url.' is down '. ' this is the status Code: '. $resCode);

        }else{
                $this->reporter->slack($notification->website_url . ':' . '  is up' . ' this is the status code!' . ' @- ' .$resCode,
                        $notification->slack_channel);
        }
    }

    private function sendNotification(Notification $notification, Status $status, $status_health, $frequency, $resCode)
    {
        $elapsed_time = \Carbon\Carbon::parse($status_health['timestamp'])->diffInMinutes();

        if ($elapsed_time >= $frequency) {

            $this->addStatusToNotification($notification, $status, $resCode);
        } 
        if ($resCode === 200){

            if($resCode <> $status_health['value']){
                var_dump($status_health['value']);
                die();
                $this->report($notification, $resCode);

            }
        }else{
            if($resCode === $status_health['value'] && $elapsed_time >= $notification->alert_frequency){
                $this->report($notification, $resCode);

            }
        }
    }


    public function status()
    {
        $notifications = Notification::where('active', 1)->get();

        $status = Status::where('name', 'health')->first();

        foreach ($notifications as $notification) {
            $this->updateStatus($notification, $status);
        }
    }

    private function updateStatus(Notification $notification, Status $status)
    {
        $resCode = $this->getStatusCode($notification->website_url);

        $this->sendNotification(
            $notification,
            $status,
            $notification->status('health'),
            $this->getFrequency($notification,$resCode),
            $resCode
            );
    }

    private function getFrequency(Notification $notification) 
    {           

            return isset($notification->check_frequency)
            ? intval($notification->check_frequency)
            : $this->default_check_frequency;                
    }

    private function getStatusCode($url)
    {
        try {
            $response = $this->client->get($url, [
                'http_errors' => false
                ]);
            return $response->getStatusCode();  
        } catch (\GuzzleHttp\Exception\ConnectException $e) {

        }
    }
}
```

this is actually where iam getting the status_health, the model, either up or dawn from the data base

```
<?php

namespace App;
use App\Status;
use App\Notification;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Notification extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['id','website_url','email','slack_channel','check_frequency','alert_frequency','speed_frequency','active'];

    public function statuses(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Status')->withPivot('values')->withTimestamps();
    }

    public function status($s_type)
    {
        if (!in_array($s_type, ['speed', 'health'])){
            return false;
        }

        $o_status = Status::where('name', strval($s_type))->first();
        $o_response = $this->statuses()->where('status_id', $o_status->id)
        ->select('values', 'created_at')->orderBy('created_at','DESC')->first();

        if($o_response === null){
            return false;
        }

        return [
            'value' => $o_response->values,
            'timestamp' => $o_response->created_at
        ];
    }

    public function history($s_type)
    {
        if (!in_array($s_type, ['speed', 'health'])){
            return false;
        }

        $o_status = Status::where('name', strval($s_type))->first();
        $o_response = $this->statuses()->where('status_id', $o_status->id)
        ->select('values', 'created_at')->orderBy('created_at','DESC')->get();

        if($o_response === null || $o_response->count() === 0){
            return false;
        }


        $a_ret = [];
        $last = null;

        foreach ($o_response as $o_status) {
            if($last != $o_status->values) {
                $a_ret[] = [
                'value' => $o_status->values,
                'timestamp' => $o_status->created_at
                ];
                $last = $o_status->values;
            }
        }
        return $a_ret;
    }
}
```

Comment: Obviously the code to check if the resp code changed does not work as expected. Make sure `$status_health` contains what you expect it to have.

Answer (score 0):

You could save the status to the database, if the status you got from the last check if different than the status you saved to the database you can send the notification and update the status in de database.

With this method the notification will be send only once the status changed and not every time you check the status.

If you check you `status_code` with the latest check you saved in your database you can compare and consider to sent the notification.

When you call the function that will send the new status you could check if the `status_code` != `old_status_code`.

Hope this works!

Comment: Yes, but if the check runs every minute, he gets every minute a notification... therefor he should use the status he got from the previous check.

Comment: i dont think there is a need for extra table because in the model the data the status code is extracted only the latest one. and checked with the new status code.

Comment: @abrahamfoto that's true, he could check the last check that's saved to the database and compare this with the new status.

Comment: that is exactly what it is going now. coz if u check the sendNotification function. it first call the addNotification function which attaches the latest response code and save it to the database and then it checks the response code and the status_health['value'], that is the latest saved response code. Sorry iam not defending my code.  am trying to make it more clear to you.

Comment: i think it fails to check the last saved status code. because the notification is keeping coming while the website is up or down even thought there is no change in the status code

Comment: What did you got from the last_status?

Comment: i am debugging it. status_health['value'] should have a wrong data....i will var_dump it and check the value.

Comment: @ Robin Dirksen. i var dum it but it has a right data. it var dumps "up" whick is correct

Comment: So it still send the slack notification?

Comment: send even though it is not supposed to send

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer after lots of debugging. the problem was not with the codes itself. the response code from http request is a string of number exmaple 200,404 etc then it is saved as string values as "up" or "down". when i use comparing the resCode (response code) and the status_health['value']( the value that i get from database which is a string "up" or "down". i was literally comparing string with int values. then i changed the resCode to string and my problem is fixed. the code in the sendNotification function is improved. Tnx for all who tried to help @Robin Dirksen . here is the new code.

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use \GuzzleHttp\Client;
use App\Utilities\Reporter;
use GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException;
use App\Notification;
use App\Status;
use App\Setting;
use Carbon;
class GuzzleController extends Controller
{
    private $default_check_frequency;

    protected $client;

    protected $reporter;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->client = new Client();

        $this->reporter = new Reporter;

        $this->default_check_frequency = Setting::defaultCheckFrequency();


    }

    private function addStatusToNotification(Notification $notification, Status $status, $resCode)
    {
        $notification->statuses()->attach($status, [
            'values' => $resCode === 200
            ? 'up'
            : 'down'
            ]);
    }

    private function report(Notification $notification, $resCode)
    {
       if(empty($resCode)){
            $resCode = "no response found";
        }
        if($resCode <> 200){
                $this->reporter->slack($notification->website_url . ':' . '  is down' . ' this is the status code!' . ' @- ' .$resCode,
                        $notification->slack_channel);

                $this->reporter->mail($notification->email,$notification->website_url.' is down '. ' this is the status Code: '. $resCode);

        }else{
                $this->reporter->slack($notification->website_url . ':' . '  is up' . ' this is the status code!' . ' @- ' .$resCode,
                        $notification->slack_channel);
        }
    }

    private function sendNotification(Notification $notification, Status $status, $status_health, $frequency, $resCode)
    {
        $elapsed_time = \Carbon\Carbon::parse($status_health['timestamp'])->diffInMinutes();

        if ($elapsed_time >= $frequency) {

            $this->addStatusToNotification($notification, $status, $resCode);
        }

        if ($resCode === 200){
            $resCode ='up';
            if($resCode <> $status_health['value']){               
                $this->report($notification, $resCode);               
            }
        }else{
            $resCode ='down';
            if($resCode <> $status_health['value'] ){
                $this->report($notification, $resCode);
            }else{
                if($elapsed_time >= $notification->alert_frequency){
                     $this->report($notification, $resCode);
                }
            }

                /*if($elapsed_time >= $notification->alert_frequency){*/

               /* }*/               

        }
    }


    public function status()
    {
        $notifications = Notification::where('active', 1)->get();

        $status = Status::where('name', 'health')->first();

        foreach ($notifications as $notification) {
            $this->updateStatus($notification, $status);
        }
    }

    private function updateStatus(Notification $notification, Status $status)
    {
        $resCode = $this->getStatusCode($notification->website_url);

        $this->sendNotification(
            $notification,
            $status,
            $notification->status('health'),
            $this->getFrequency($notification,$resCode),
            $resCode
            );
    }

    private function getFrequency(Notification $notification) 
    {           

            return isset($notification->check_frequency)
            ? intval($notification->check_frequency)
            : $this->default_check_frequency;                
    }

    private function getStatusCode($url)
    {
        try {
            $response = $this->client->get($url, [
                'http_errors' => false
                ]);
            return $response->getStatusCode();  
        } catch (\GuzzleHttp\Exception\ConnectException $e) {

        }
    }
}
```